# Where is the information for debian control files stored?

Tags: apt, dpkg

The documentation for Debian and the dpkg package managment system explains the debian/control files are meta data for packages, e.g. [these docs](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/debian-dir-overview.html#the-control-file) explain:

> The control file contains the information that the package manager (such as apt-get, synaptic, and adept) uses, build-time dependencies, maintainer information, and much more.

On ubuntu the file `/var/lib/dpkg/status` contains the contents of installed packages control files, but when ever I have extracted packages I have never seen a control file in the package itself.
My understanding the APT/DPKG system that ubuntu and debian uses is that the `apt-get update` command will connect to all defined repositories and pull down a `package.gz` file for each repo.
In that case does the data defined in each packages control file get stored in the `package.gz` so that it is available to the `apt-cache` system - rather than directly to dpkg.
This makes sense to me because that would supply the meta data for a package to the `apt-cache showpkg` command without having to install the package.
If this is not the case then where are the debian control files stored?

Comment: Isn't it in the .deb file itself in file named control.tar.gz?

Comment: @siblynx Ive never seen it, can you give an example of a package that has it?

Comment: Each .deb usually contains two files: `data.tar.gz` (actual package contents) and `control.tar.gz`, which contains file `control` with information you mentioned. It also contains file `debian-binary`, it's probably a version number of .deb file format. I don't know which tool you've used to unpack .deb files, but I recomment you to start with `ar`, because each .deb is a simple ar archive.

Comment: For example, I downloaded libc6 from http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.19-18+deb8u2_i386.deb, now I list it's contents: `ar t libc6_2.19-18+deb8u2_i386.deb` which displays: `debian-binary
control.tar.gz
data.tar.gz
`

Comment: thanks @siblynx ! I was was using `dpkg -x <package>` to extract - and for some reason it was stripping all the important files out during the extraction - `ar` shows the true state of affairs !

Comment: Nice to see it did help!

Answer (score 1):

The format of the .deb packages is documented in the `deb(5)` man page.

You can also see the control information for a .deb with `dpkg-deb -I archive.deb` or `dpkg-deb -f archive.deb`.